# XML to JSON getJSONArray() issues

Tags: java, json, xml

I read XML from a URL as Follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;


public class WebGet {

public static void disableCertificateValidation() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }
    };

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);

    String credentials = "user" + ":" + "psw";
    String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    URL url = new URL("someURL");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoding));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String apiResponse = "";
    while ((apiResponse = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(apiResponse);
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
    JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(sb.toString());
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    System.out.println(jsonObj);
    jsonObj.getJSONArray("devices");

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    disableCertificateValidation();
}
}
```

Everything prints and works fine except the "jsonObj.getJSONArray("devices");" which throws the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["devices"] is not a JSONArray.
>       at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:622)

My Output is show here:

{"devices": {
    "total": 71,
    "count": 71,
    "device": [
        {
            "domain_id": 1,
            "offline": false,
            "domain_name": "Default",
            "vendor": "Cisco",
            "topology": true,
            "ip": "22.201.120.101",
            "name": "eagnmn-red-rdmvpn",
            "model": "asa",
            "id": 55
        },
        {
            "domain_id": 1,
            "offline": false,
            "domain_name": "Default",
            "vendor": "Cisco",
            "topology": true,
            "ip": "22.201.120.51",
            "name": "eagnmn-red-ras",
            "model": "asa",
            "id": 54
        },

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does the printout of sb look like?

Comment: How does your XML look like ? Vers likely `XML.toJSONObject` does not understand that the content below 'devices' is an array

Comment: Add in your long line anyway - without seeing what your output is it'll be difficult to assist beyond whats already been said

Comment: I can't get the XML to paste in correctly. How can I get it in here without it being formatted

Comment: `devices` is `JSONObject`  `{}`  not `JSONArray` `[]` so use `jsonObj.getJSONObject("devices")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

```
JSONArray deviceArray = jsonObj.getJSONObject("devices").getJSONArray("device")
```

because your object contains `devices` `JSONObject` which further contains your `device` `JSONArray`